# Unix TimeStamp - Конвертация времени

Tags: время, unix, дата

Вот нашел такое решение:

```
date -d "$(echo "05/Apr/2010:00:22:46 +0300" | perl -pe 's/\//-/g ; s/:/ /')" +%s
```

На выводе получаем дату в секундах с 19700101 (1270416166). Проблема в том, что передается месяц в строковом формате. При попытке подачи в числовом - неправильный формат даты.

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Как конвертировать, например, такую строку:

> 05-04-2010 00:22:46

в Unix TimeStamp формат.

Comment: Про PHP речи не ведется.
Есть командная строка (BASH).

Comment: что мешает выполнить php скрипт из bash?

Comment: А Вы всегда ходите в магазин через Китай ? Нужно делать не так как можно, а как как правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть решение, приятное тем, что использует только стандартную утилиту `date`:

```
date --date="2010-04-05 00:22:46" +%s
```

Но есть недостаток: именно тот формат, который Вам нужен, `date` не понимает (поскольку он не очень распространён в США, думаю).
Цитата из мана:

> The --date=STRING is a mostly free
> format human readable date string such
> as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"
> or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next
> Thursday".  A date string may contain
> items indicating calendar  date,  time
> of  day, time zone, day of week,
> relative time, relative date, and
> numbers.  An empty string indicates
> the beginning of the day.  The date
> string format is more complex than is
> easily documented here but is fully
> described in the info documentation.

Если нужен именно тот формат, ну переставьте там числа местами с помощью `sed`.

---

Бонус: комплект с мега-сложным perl-скриптом, переворачивающим дату:

```
date -d "$(echo "05-04-2010 00:22:46 +0300" | perl -pe 's/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/\3-\2-\1/;')" +%s
```

Comment: Четко :))) ...Спасибо :) !

Answer (score 0):

```
$ php -r 'echo strtotime("05-04-2010 00:22:46");'
1270416166
```

Вообще, strtotime понимает очень много форматов.
Или написать свой парсер который по некоторым эвристикам будет определять правильный формат и делать соответсвующий конверт даты

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед ? ... Почти всегда есть все готовое. Просто мы не всегда о нем знаем :)

Comment: Поднимать тут PHP — это из пушки по воробьям. (не считая того, что вообще php не самый хороший, эффективный и удобный язык)